# PHP array_push em array dentro de outro array

Tags: php, array

Boa noite, eu preciso criar um código em php que atenda a seguinte situação:

Tenho um array de arrays 
$arrayTudo = [$array1, $array2, $array3];

Calculo um valor X e quero jogá-lo no array1, por exemplo. Podia ser em qualquer um deles. Como fazer o array_push nesse caso? É possível jogar esse valor X num array dentro de outro array?

Antes de codificar preciso entender como fazer isso.

Seria mais ou menos assim:

```
<%php
$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];
$array3 = [];

$arrayTudo = [$array1, $array2, $array3];

$x = 10;


array_push($arrayTudo[0], $x);
%>
```

seleciono um dos arrays para receber o valor X. O primeiro array, por exemplo. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um `array_merge` neste caso. Veja:

```
$arrayTudo = [array1, array2, array3];

$x = 10;
$y = 20;

$arrayValores = [$arrayTudo[0] => [$x, $y]];

$result = array_merge($arrayTudo, $arrayValores);
```

Os resultados:

```
var_dump($result[array1]);
```

Saída:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => int 10
  1 => int 20
```

Tudo:

```
 var_dump($result);
```

Saída:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'array1' (length=6)
  1 => string 'array2' (length=6)
  2 => string 'array3' (length=6)
  'array1' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 10
      1 => int 20
```

Comment: Entendi. Acho que essa é a lógica que precisava. Vou testar. obrigado.

Comment: @Ronda disponha

Answer (score 0):

Procure por "matriz", as vezes te ajuda...

Ficaria + - assim:

```
$array[0][0] = 10; 
$array[0][1] = 20;
```

[Veja esse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8Gr2NIMxQQ)

Numa estrutura de repetição, você terá que saber como colocar cada um:

```
$a = 0;
while ($a < 3) {

   $b = 0;
   while ($b < 5) {

   $array[$a][$b] = $b*2;

   $b++;
   }

$a++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 8
        )

)
```